# Resizing Detail View Controller in UISplitViewController [ iPad landscape only]

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on iPad landscape only version. I added splitViewController and assigned a viewController as detail view. I am using this view controller out side the splitViewController also as a full view viewController.

Problem : viewController is not resizing when its in splitViewController as detil view. i.e anyting which is on right corner of the view is out of visibel area.

P.S : I am using storyboard with autolayout ,Xcode 5.1

Comment: I am also seeing this. Have you had any success solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by removing and adding back the view programmatically .

```
[self.segmentButtonBgView removeFromSuperview];
[self.segmentButtonBgView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.segmentButtonBgView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.segmentButtonBgView.frame.origin.x-158, self.segmentButtonBgView.frame.origin.y,405, self.segmentButtonBgView.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.segmentButtonBgView];
```

All subviews of segmentButtonBgView will resize if you have set constraints.